# Update netrw to newer version

Tags: netrw

I use Vim from this ppa

http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu

which includes netrw v156

How can I update to a newer netrw

--> Do I have to remove netrw installed
--> Can I simply install a newer netrw in .vim/plugins and this will take precedence over the system-wide one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newrw is distributed as a Vimball. After you download the new version, move netrw.vba.gz to ~/.vim. Then open it with vim, e.g.,

```
$ vim netrw.vba.gz
```

You will see this message at the bottom of the screen:

```
***vimball*** Source this file to extract it! (:so %)
```

Execute `:so %` and the plugin files will be extracted into the autoload, doc, plugin and syntax subdirectories of your ~/.vim directory. The next time you start Vim, it will automatically use the new version of netrw. You don't have to do anything with old version of netrw.